# ImportError: cannot import name 'MPRester' from 'pymatgen' (unknown location)

Tags: python

I am using python 3.8.5 in jupyter notebook. I am getting an error while doing:

```
from matminer.data_retrieval.retrieve_MP import MPDataRetrieval
mpdr = MPDataRetrieval(api_key='my_api_key')
```

The error is :

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'MPRester' from 'pymatgen' (unknown location)
```

I have installed pymatgen and matminer. Why did this error occur?

Answer (score 4):

It was moved to `from pymatgen.ext.matproj import MPRester`.

So the matminer code is outdated, try updating it and/or downgrading your pymatgen package to an older version.

see [pymatgen docs](https://pymatgen.org/pymatgen.ext.matproj.html?highlight=mprester).

Comment: oh，thank you very much！！It has puzzled me for a long time